Two Virtual Application in Sames IIS Site, but unable to pass session value by using Session State
Despite configuring the XML snippet provided for both applications and enabling the ASP.NET State Service, my VB .NET 4.8 application continues to encounter difficulties in passing session data to another application.
My virtual application is host under same IIS Site, and same application pool as well.
I had enabled the ASP.NET State Service in services.

What difficulties did you encounter? Is the code not working? If yes please share your code, If not, please post more details information about your requirement.
